# url slash and space replacement with _-_-- or _-_-_

Tags: php, url, str-replace

i have code which from given path makes something like breadcrumb navigation. I didnt wrote that code, but i think i understand it except two things in url replacement.

Code is like this, and i cant figure out, why replace space with `_-_--` and slash with `_-_-_`. Is there some common point in this?

```
function listLinksRecursive($path){

echo "<br>recursive : " . $path;
$path = str_replace("X:/","",$path);
$path = str_replace("X:","",$path);
$header = str_replace("_"," ", $path);
echo "<br>first header ". $header;
$header = str_replace("-"," ", $header);
echo "<br>second header ". $header;
echo "<br>";
$linksarray = explode ("/",$header);
$linksarrayreal = explode("/",str_replace(" ","_-_--",$path));
var_dump($linksarray);
echo "<br>";
var_dump($linksarrayreal);

echo "FOLDER: ";
echo ("<a href='http://sjabcz-vyv-bck/cae/index.php?lvl=0&idpath=' rel='nofollow'>04_Knowledge-base</a> / ");

for ($i=0; $i < count($linksarray); $i++){
    $linkpath = "";
    for ($j = 0; $j <=$i; $j++){

        $linkpath = $linkpath . $linksarrayreal[$j];
        if ($j < $i){
            $linkpath = $linkpath . "_-_-_";
        }
    }

    if ($i < count($linksarray)-1){
        echo ("<a href = 'http://sjabcz-vyv-bck/cae/index.php?lvl=0&idpath=$linkpath' rel='nofollow'>$linksarray[$i]</a> / ");
    }

    if ($i == count($linksarray)-1){
        echo ("<b>$linksarray[$i]</b>");
    }
}

echo "<p>";
```

}

Comment: your tags seem wrong? what does this have to do with regex? and space and slash have stated in their description they should not be used.

Comment: my bad, i accepted all tags which SO suggested

Comment: @LubosSuk See the code properly in this code it replace these.

Comment: @SunilPachlangia sorry but i didnt understand your comment :/

Comment: @LubosSuk See this line $linksarrayreal = explode("/",str_replace(" ","_-_--",$path)); in  this line you are replacing space with _-_--

Comment: @SunilPachlangia yes, i know. But i dont know why. As i wrote, this isnt my code, im refactoring old code, and trying to figure out why to replace space with that

Comment: @LubosSuk That depends on developer and need of that time if now its making problem then change code a per need